# Где в Windows Сэвэн автозагрузка?

Tags: windows-7, автозапуск

Вопрос стыдный (всё-таки с ПК с начала века)
Но, где в Windows Сэвэн автозагрузка?
Через реестр или через msconfig - иногда зачем строить комбайн ради срезания одного колоска?
И вернёмся к вопросу - где в Win7 та, старая, удобная и простая папочка "Автозагрузка"Кинул ярлычёк и спокоен. Где это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ага! Разработчики Win7 вернулись к Английскому!
Как в старые добрые Win95, Win98. Рабочий стол стал Desktop, Документы стали Documents и т.д.
Возврат к прошлому? Наверное в 95-ом, грамотнее ОС сибирали менее торопились с продажами видать.
Одним словом каталог Автозагрузки в Win 7 (стыдно, как IT'шнику признаться, но прочитал на ответах майл у детишек) тут:
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\  
Запрячут, так запрячут...И говорят, что ОСи становяться всё проще и удобнее.

---

Answer (score 3):

Какбэ Пуск - Все программы - листаем вниз до папочки "Автозагрузка"...

Comment: А я вам скажу, что в ОСях последнего поколения, явно прослеживается тенденция применения архитектуры Front-end и Back-end приложений.